# I need to add pass a list to a view but I am getting an error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ado.net

I get the error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues, string dataGroupField)

Where my controller is

```cs
DataSet rolelist = _userService.GetUserRole();
            List<SelectListItem> listo = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in rolelist.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                listo.Add(new SelectListItem { 
                    Text = dr["user_role_name"].ToString(),
                    Value = dr["user_role_Id"].ToString() });
            }
            ViewBag.urolelist = listo;
```

and my view is

```xml
 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Rolename" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Rolename" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.urolelist,"Value","Text"))"></Select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Rolename" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

and my repo is

```cs
 public DataSet GetUserRole()
        {
            try
            {
                using (con = new SqlConnection(Constr))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserRoleso", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sqlData.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I put the below code in a get controller and everything is fine

```cs
DataSet rolelist = _userService.GetUserRole();
List<SelectListItem> listo = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (DataRow dr in rolelist.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    listo.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["user_role_name"].ToString(), Value = dr["user_role_Id"].ToString() }); }
    ViewBag.urolelist = listo;
```

Why does the first controller implementation throw, but the second doesn't?

Comment: i guess it was suppose to be in the get method and not post method

Answer (score 0):

Without any data from get controller, it means the ViewBag.urolelist is null, so passing null to SelectList that what makes the runtime complain about it.

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')

As you can see the first parameter of SelectList is IEnumerable items

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, ...
```

which is the ViewBag.urolelist in your view

```
asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.urolelist,...
```